# Is it possible to use xml intellisense in vb.net code in visual studio 2010?

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm currently learning the XML features of VB.NET and Visual Studio 2010, and I have learned how I can enable intellisense in a XML file by associating it with a schema, and this works well. However since I'm mostly generating xml and not reading data from an xml file, I would like to be able to do the same when writing xml in a VB.NET module, class etc.

e.g. when writing xml directly in vb.net code like this:

```
Dim JohnDoe As XElement = <Person Name="John Doe">
                              <Height>180</Height>
                              <HeightUnit>Meter</HeightUnit>
                              <HeightUnitType>Metric</HeightUnitType>
                          </Person>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: A search for `xml intellisense vb` found this as the second result: [How to: Enable XML IntelliSense in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531402.aspx). Have you tried those things? What else have you tried to do? What went wrong?

Comment: I have already read that article, and making a schema as well as getting intellisense to work in an XML file is no problem. I think its the import XML namespace part that I don't really understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the problem was that a targetNamespace attribute has to be added manually to my schema in order for me to be able to import it.